# Nginx and AJAX deny

Tags: ajax, nginx

How can I denny users from accessing some url in my site but allow an ajax service to access it.
I was thinking to do something like this in NGINX:

```
/location something.html {
 allow 127.0.0.1;
 deny all;
}
```

So anyone who tries to enter *mydomain.com/something.html* from the browser with any IP gets a 403 but the ajax call that is running from localhost can access the url.

Although this is not working.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: If an AJAX request can touch it, a user can touch it. There’s no stopping that.

Comment: Strange queries, such as this one, are almost invariably down to the XY Problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/175227